# Track download date in installer file

Tags: .net, installation, windows

I have a requirement to restrict my installer expiry to be one month from the date its been downloaded. The restriction starts from the date of downloading the installer file (Not the date of installing the software). Is their any method to mark the downloaded date in installer file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "created" file attribute wont solve the issue, because whenever we copy the files to a different location the 'Created' time stamp was getting reset.
The solution was to whenever the user Clicks on the download file action, create a time stamp file dynamically and package along with the installer as a zip. This is like a config file which will be deployed with package installer, and a reference to verify the download time. The Contents should be encrypted in the file  in order to protect from any user manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Mark of the Web](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) attribute should tell you the file was downloaded from the web.

Regarding the date it was downloaded, well that is equal with the ["Created" file attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx), that you see when checking the properties of a file.